# Python pandas data frame/dictionary to csv

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need some assistance formatting a python pandas data frame that is written to a csv. The data frame consists of multiple data dictionaries. The dictionary keys are printing fine, but I need the values to be written in separate rows down a column and without the square brackets and quotation marks. I have been scratching my head over this. I have tried pd.wide_to_long and getting creative with pandas melt. However, the outputs are not what I need.

Currently dictionary values look like this in a single cell:

Key
['a''b''c''d']

I would like a, b, c, d printed down a single column:
Key
a
b
c
d

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a dictionary in the constructor of a dataframe like this

```
mp = {'key0': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 
      'key1': [1, 2, 3, 4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=mp)

print(df)

   key0 key1
0   a    1
1   b    2
2   c    3
3   d    4
```

Make sure all the lists have the same size though.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. I tried this but my output still looks the same. I may have a data type issue - one key:value set has a string data type, but the other key:value pairs are string:float64. I'll try to make the data types consistent for all the dictionaries.